# Linux shell wrap a program's stdin and stdout using pipes

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, pipe, mkfifo

So, I have this interactive program that is running on an embedded linux ARM platform with no screen and that I cannot modify. To interact with it I have to ssh into the embedded linux distro, and run the program which is some sort of custom command line with builtin commands, and it does not exit, only SIGINT will quit the program.

I'm trying to automate it by letting it run in the background and communicate with it using pipes by sending SSH commands like this `ssh user@host echo "command" > stdinpipe`. This part works, I've been provided with an example like this in a shell script (I cannot use bash, I only have ash installed on the machine) :

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo somePipe
/proc/<PID>/exe < somePipe 2>&1 &
```

I can now easily command the program by writing to the pipe like

```
echo "command" > somePipe
```

and it outputs everything inside the terminal. The problem is that while it works if I have an SSH session open, it won't if I only send commands one by one as I said earlier (I'm using paramiko in python with the `exec_command()` method, just in case, but I don't think that is relevant, I could use `invoke_session()` but I don't want to have to deal with `recv()`)

So I figured out I'd redirect the output of the program to a pipe. That's where problems arise. My first attempt was this one (please ignore the fact that everything is run as root and stored in the root home folder, that's how I got it and I don't have the time to make it cleaner now, plus I'm not the one managing the software) :

```
cd /root/binary

mkfifo outpipe
mkfifo inpipe

./command_bin &

# find PID automatically
command_pid=$(ps -a | egrep ' * \.\/command_bin *' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')
/proc/${command_pid}/exe < inpipe 2>&1 & 

 echo "process ./command_bin running on PID ${command_pid}"
```

That alone works within the terminal itself. Now if I leave the SSH session open and open another terminal and type `ssh root@host "echo command > /root/binary/inpipe"` the code gets executed, but then it outputs the command I just typed and its result into the other terminal that stayed open. So it is obviously not an option, I have to capture the output somehow.

If I change `./command_bin &` for `./command_bin >outpipe &` the program never starts, I have no idea why, I know that because `$command_pid` is empty and I cannot find the process with `ps -A`

Now if instead I replace `/proc/${command_pid}/exe < inpipe 2>&1 &` with `/proc/${command_pid}/exe < inpipe &>outpipe &` the program starts, I can write to inpipe just fine with `echo "command" > inpipe` when the script finished running, however if I try any of `cat < outpipe`, `tail outpipe` it just hangs, and does nothing. I've tried using `nohup` when starting the command but it doesn't really help. I've also tried using a normal file for redirecting the output instead of a fifo, but with the exact same results.

I've spent the entire day on this thing and I cannot get it to work. Why is this not working ? Also I am probably just using an awful way to do this, is there any other way ? The only thing that's mandatory here is that I have to connect through ssh to the board and the command line utility has to stay open because it is communicating with onboard devices (using I2C, OneWire protocols etc).

To keep it simple I want to be able to write to the program's stdin whenever I want, get its stdout to go somewhere else (some file, buffer, I do not care) that I can easily retrieve later after an arbitrary amount of time  with cat, tail or some other command with ssh.

Comment: Is using the `expect` program an option?  It is designed to drive interactive programs.

Comment: I could, because basically I need to automate this program, but I also need to be able to interface it to a PyQt application I'm writing on my actual computer (which is also on Linux, so I don't care if the solution isn't portable), I need to be able to retrieve values from the command line when I send a query to the program, and update the GUI on the other side accordingly. I don't know if that's feasible with expect. I could try Pexpect in my Python code though, I've never really used it.